# what do these vectors span

Tags: linear-algebra

What do the following vectors span?

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}4\\5\\1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}5\\7\\4\end{array}\right) $$

I have tried the gaussian elimination method and end up with the matrix :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1& 4& 5\\ 0& -3& -3\\ 0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$

The rank of this matrix is 2 and first two vectors are independent .How do i tell what do these vectors span? In my notes its given they span a 2D subspace of R^3 but i don't understand how we conclude this

Comment: If two of the vectors are linearly independent that means that the span of the three given vectors is all the linear combinations of the first two vectors. These linear combinations are a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, because it has a basis with two vectors and because these linear combinations form a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ which we would intuitively call two-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your findings. Note how you can arrive at these more easily by seeing that if your above vectors are $x,y,z$, you get $x+y=z \land \forall c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{{0\}}: x \neq c \cdot y$

So clearly, $x,y$ are independent, but $x,y,z$ are not. 2 independent vectors span a 2-dimensional subspace (you can imagine them forming a plane, $x,y$ are the directions that define that plane and you find particular points in that plane by evaluating linear combinations of $x,y$).

More formally you would denote this as $span(x,y)=\{\lambda_{1} x+\lambda_{2} y \mid \lambda_{1} ,\lambda_{2} \in \mathbb{R}\}$.